# Assembly code causes recursion

Tags: c++, c, assembly, x86

I've been writing a C application, and I came in need of x86 assembly language. I'm pretty new to assembly, and the following snippet causes recursion:

```
unsigned int originalBP;
unsigned fAddress;
void f(unsigned short aa) {
    printf("Function %d\n", aa);
}

unsigned short xx = 77;
void redirect() {
    asm {
        pop originalBP
        mov fAddress, offset f
        push word ptr xx
        push fAddress
        push originalBP
    }
}
```

If i call `redirect` , it will repeatedly output: "Function 1135"

First, here are a few information about the environment in which this code is executed:

- This code is written to be executed under  [NTVDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_DOS_machine)
- Tiny memory model is used ( all segment pointer registers point to the same segment )

Here's my expectation of what the code above should do ( this is most likely the culprit of the error ) :

- Pop the stack and store value in `originalBP`; I believe the value is actually the address of the current function i.e. `redirect`
- Push `f`'s argument value ( value of `xx` ) to the stack
- Push address of `f` to stack ( since there's only one segment, only offset is needed )
- Push back the address of `redirect`

Of course, if this were the correct flow, recursion would be apparent ( except the part where 1135 is printed instead of 7). But interestingly, doing the same with a function with no arguments produces only one line of output i.e.:

```
unsigned int originalBP;
unsigned fAddress;
void f() {
    printf("Function");
}


void redirect() {
    asm {
        pop originalBP
        mov fAddress, offset f
        push fAddress
        push originalBP
    }
}
```

This probably means that my understanding of the above code is completely wrong. What is the real issue in this code?

**EDIT:** I probably left some of the things unsaid:

- This is a 16 bit application
- Compiler used is Borland C++ 3.1, as Eclipse plugin
- `redirect` is called from `main` as `redirect()`

**EDIT (regarding Margaret Bloom's answer)** Here's an example of instruction execution once `redirect` is called. Values in brackets represent stack pointer register and the value at that location before each instruction is executed:

- call redirect
- (FFF4-04E6) `push bp`
- (FFF2-FFF6) `mov bp, sp`
- (FFF2-FFF6) `mov fAddress, offest f`
- (FFF2-FFF6) `pop originalBP`
- (FFF4-04E6) `pop originalRIP`
- (FFF6-0000) `push xx` (I've changed xx to 1187)
- (FFF4-0755) `push originalRIP`
- (FFF2-04E6) `push fAddress`
- (FFF0-04AC) `push originalBP`
- (FFEE-FFF6) `pop bp`
- (FFF0-04AC) `ret`

  - (in f) (FFF2-04E6) `push bp`
  - (FFF0-FFF6) `mov bp,sp`
  - printf executes
  - (FFF0-FFF6) `pop bp`
  - (FFF2-04E6) `ret`
    Next statements seems to be `return 0;` which is the end of main.

Execution continues trough bunch of lines, and somehow comes back to the line calling `redirect`.

Comment: I don't know the environment, but why are you manipulating the stack to perform a function call? And originalBP will contain the original BP, not the return address. For that, you must pop one more. And be sure to push back as many items as you pop, not more, not less. But why don't you simply **call** f the normal way?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis It's not about function calls per se, since the final goal of the application is to implement threads from scratch ( the task is to write a small kernel ), and  in a multithreaded environment with interrupt, I won't always be able to just call functions ( at least i think so )

Comment: @degeneration Why do you think that you won't be able to “just call function?”

Comment: @FUZxxl Because ( I believe ) when I need a context switch,  I won't be able to know what function I need to call, I'll just know where i need to go next i.e. what thread.

Comment: @degeneration Yes, on context switch that is the case. But in all other cases you can still call functions as usual. I'm not sure how your code is related to context switching though, such a thing is done somewhat differently.

Comment: @FUZxxl To be honest, I'm not quite sure I'm ready for writing any kind of kernel, but it's a challenge :) You're definitely right about this not being related to context switching. Again, to be honest, this was a snippet of code that came as an example in project materials. It's labeled "calling a hidden function", which in the example makes no sense, since the signature of the function is known , and hence it's not hidden. I didn't really ask "why", just "how" :)

Comment: I see. Well, this looks a lot like it tries to call the function by pudding its address on the stack and then executing a `ret`. Though, it seems to do this somewhat wrong. Perhaps you could ask whomever wrote the project materials for clarification?

Comment: @FUZxxl Actually, the second example was provided. I was curious to see how would passing the arguments work  this way.

Comment: @degeneration Looking at it again, if a stack frame is provided, than the code is almost correct, except that returning won't work because no return address has been pushed.

Comment: If you change 77 with different numbers (say 0 or 65530), does it keep looping or show "random" behavior?

Comment: @MargaretBloom OKay, so i tried with other values, and i kept getting the same line "Function 1135" once, but then complete rubbish "%( (null)% )%(..". Some values just crash the NVDTM. Can you explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't post what compiler and compiling options you use to code that `redirect`.

With optimizations ON, you can't assume the full C function prologue/epilogue will be used, so you are operating with stack without any idea of it's layout (if there would be zero prologue/epilogue, then you did inject 2 values ahead of return address to caller, so redirect would simply return to caller (main?) which may essentially just exit -> no call to `f` = not your case).

As inside the asm block you already have the fn address, why don't you simply call it? The stack would be like: somebody calls redirect -> redirect calls some address -> address fn() -> returns to redirect -> returns to caller.

It looks to me like you are trying to modify it to: somebody calls redirect -> redirect calls some address -> address fn() -> returns to caller (skipping return to redirect). As the redirect epilogue is tiny bit of code, I don't see much benefit of that modification (also I don't see how it is "context switch" related).

Anyway, check your compiler options how to produce the assembly listing of final code to see how it does really compile, or even better, check it with debugger (step per instruction on assembly level).

---

EDIT (after providing the debug info):

when you get to `return 0`, there's additional alien `xx` injected in stack (`sp` being `0xFFF4`) instead of `sp` being original `FFF6` pointing to the `0`.

The end of `main` probably does not handle this correctly (doing `pop bp` `ret` I guess), assuming the `sp` is correct upon return. (would it do the other C epilogue including `mov sp,bp`, it would probably survive your stack tampering).

Then again, if it would do other epilogue in all functions, it would do it in `redirect()` too, so you would have to modify `bp` as well to make the end of `redirect()` do `ret` into `fAddress`. Like `dec bp, dec bp` would probably suffice, as you have grown the stack by injecting 2B into params space.

Check the debug one more time when `return 0` in main is hit, how it is implemented, if it can cope with modified `sp` or not (well, obviously it can't, as it loops by accident into `redirect`).

If that's the case, you should probably patch the `main` to restore `sp` before `return 0;`. I wonder whether simple `mov sp,bp` would do (`bp` should be `FFF6` ahead of that).

Conclusion: tampering with stack frames across several calls is always tricky business. ;)

Comment: About context switching/etc... If this would be real context switch, that is done differently. If this should be some fake emulated context switching, you have to post some design, how it is supposed to work, but even then I think you can leave on the top of the stack the real return to some kernel fallback, if the thread would exit completely. As long as you just switch between threads, you have to switch whole stack (each thread has it's own), the code you posted is nowhere close to that (I mean it's not even 1% of 100%, it's more like unrelated, or 0.1% related).

Comment: Hmm.. thinking about it, having `redirect()` defined as global function in .c file will probably enforce the compiler to follow ABI, so assuming there's `[rip, bp]` at the stack makes some sense then (I don't know the correct 16b DOS ABI from head). Still OP providing disassembled resulting code would stop the "guess" game in this regard.

Comment: I've finally edited my answer with debug info. ( this is after  Margaret Bloom's answer )

Comment: @degeneration: well, much better. I added some notes to my answer, still a  bit guess game.

Answer (score 5):

For you second snippet, the one without arguments, the stack states are as follow:

```
Where                 | Stack (growing on the left)
----------------------+----------------------------
after redirect prolog   redirect rip, redirect bp
pop originalBP          redirect rip
push fAddress           redirect rip, fAddress
push originalBP         redirect rip, fAddress, redirect bp
after redirect epilog   redirect rip, fAddress
after redirect return   redirect rip (control moved to f)
after f prolog          redirect rip, f bp
after f epilog          redirect rip
after f return          (control moved to redirect caller)
```

Where `redirect rip` means the return address (*return IP*) of the function `redirect`.

As you can see, upon entering of `f` the stack correctly points to `redirect rip`, the return address of `redirect`.
Upon exit, the control flows back to `redirect` caller.

For your first snippet, the stack goes as follow:

```
Where                 | Stack (growing on the left)
----------------------+----------------------------
after redirect prolog   redirect rip, redirect bp
pop originalBP          redirect rip
push word ptr xx        redirect rip, xx
push fAddress           redirect rip, xx, fAddress
push originalBP         redirect rip, xx, fAddress, redirect bp
after redirect epilog   redirect rip, xx, fAddress
after redirect return   redirect rip, xx (control moved to f)
after f prolog          redirect rip, xx, f bp
after f epilog          redirect rip, xx
after f return          (control moved to xx)
```

Upon entering of `f` we have `redirect rip, xx` on the stack when we should really have `xx, redirect rip`.
with the former configuration the parameter `aa` contains the return address of `redirect` and the return address of `f` is the value of `xx`.

---

Based on your [answer to my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38951559/assembly-code-causes-recursion?noredirect=1#comment65267891_38951559) the code looped by accident.

---

If you want to call `f` with arguments, be sure to push them before the return address:

```
pop originalBP
pop originalRIP

;Arguments go here    
push xx

push originalRIP
push fAddress
push originalBP
```

Comment: Hmm, an interesting thing happened. I did as you said, and the code does print the argument correctly. But the recursion is now happening all the time, regardless of argument value.

Comment: @degeneration you don't even show how you call the `redirect()`. Don't you call it in some loop? The suggested solution is skipping return trough end of redirect: like I pointed in my answer, can't see any benefit of this (except being educational, if you would finally take a debugger and step it over on instruction level).

Comment: Mmmm, I may have messed up something. Any change you can use a debugger? Maybe printing the value of the variables involved may help

Comment: RIP is return-IP, right?  I think the OP is compiling 16-bit code because they're targeting NTVDM, so you don't mean the 64-bit version of IP/EIP.  But this is certainly what I first thought!  It would be good to explain your abbreviation somewhere.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, RIP is ambiguous. I'll edit the answer in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

So, are you heading toward something like this? (because I sort of can't exactly put my finger on where your code from question will be used then, seems like basic stack exercise to give you idea how code execution can be affected, which will later evolve probably into something like this... maybe... and maybe not).

Fake context switch in 16b in some C-like pseudo code (ok, more like comments only :) ), has to be installed as some timed interrupt:

```
// should be some "far" type function to preserve "cs" as well
far void fakeThreadSwitch() {
    asm {
        cli  ; or other means to disable thread switch (re-entry)
        ; store the current values of all registers
        pusha
        pushf
        push ds
        push es
        ; set `ds` to thread contexts data section

        ; figure out, which thread is currently running
        ; (have some "size_t currently_running = index;" in context section)

        ; if none, then pick some SLEEPING
        ; but have some [root_context] updated (.stack), so you can
        ; do final switch to it upon terminating the OS.

        ; verify the ss points to that thread stack ->
        ; if you by accident did interrupt OS kernel,
        ; then just return without touching anything (jump to "pop es")

        ; store ss:sp to [current_thread_context.stack]

        ; decide if you want to switch to some other context
        ; (or kill current) simulating "preemptive multitasking"
        ; if switch, set up all flags correctly (RUNNING/SLEEPING/index)

        ; load ss:sp from [next_thread_context.stack]

        pop es
        pop ds
        popf
        popa
        sti  ; or enable thread switch interrupt by other means
    }
}
```

Then to start some new thread executing code at fAddress:

```
void startNewThread(void far *fAddress) {
    // allocate some new context for the new thread
    // (probably fixed array for max threads, searching for "FREE" one)
    // ... (inits fields in some struct [new_thread_context])
    // allocate some new stack memory for the new thread
    // ... (sets [new_thread_context.stack_allocated])
    // set up the stack for initial threadSwitch
    uint16_t far * stackEnd = [new_thread_context.stack]
    // reserve: es,ds + flags + all + cs:ip (to be executed) + OS exit trap (3x)
    stackEnd -= (2 + 1 + 8 + 2 + 3);
    // init the values in "stack"
    stackEnd[0] = stackEnd[1] = [new_thread_context.ds]; // es, ds
    stackEnd[2] = 0; // flags
    stackEnd[3] = stackEnd[4] = stackEnd[5] = 0; // di, si, bp
    stackEnd[6] = offset(stackEnd+11); // sp ahead of "pusha"
    stackEnd[7] = stackEnd[8] = 0; // bx, dx
    stackEnd[9] = stackEnd[10] = 0; // cx, ax
    stackEnd[11] = segment(fAddress);     // "return" to fAddress
    stackEnd[12] = offset(fAddress);
    // thread_exit_return is some trap function to handle
    // far return inside fAddress code, which would probably require
    // different design to make this truly usable (to fit C epilogue of f())
    stackEnd[13] = segment(&thread_exit_return);
    stackEnd[14] = offset(&thread_exit_return);
    stackEnd[15] = thread_id;
    [new_thread_context.stack] = stackEnd;
    // all context data are ready for context switch, mark this thread "ready"
    [new_thread_context.running] = SLEEPING;

    // now in some future the context-switch may pick this thread from
    // pool of sleeping threads, and will switch execution to it
    // (through this artificially prepared stack image)
}
```

One of kernel handlers, this one designed as "landing" point for any `f()` finishing normally, which would just return (or calling this explicitly).

```
void thread_exit_return() {
    // get the exited thread_id somehow
    [thread_context.running] = FINISHED;
    // deallocate [thread_context.stack_allocated]
    // deallocate thread context (marking it as "FREE"?)
}
```

Would require some more thought and design how to run kernel itself (whether in just another thread, or in the original app context), and how to give it running time. And how to control kernel to execute new threads, or kill/exit old ones.

Anyway, the important part of this exercise is that push-all-in-thread-stack / pop-all-from-other-stack, to give you rough idea how preemptive multitasking works (although in 32b protected OS this involves much more trickery with CPU switching to protected layer (and back to user land) and using different stack for kernel, etc.. so only the principle is same).

Of course in 16b unprotected this is quite fragile construction, which can be damaged across different threads easily (and I very likely did oversight something important, so it would require very likely some heavy bug fixing to make it work).